# SFDX: Profile changes not being recognized on Source:Pull

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, force-cli

I recently just spun up a new scratch org. Afterwards I pushed my current source repo using `source:push`. I noticed that apparently tab visibility was not set for some of my custom tabs/objects. I turned those on for the `admin.profile` and I attempted a `source:pull` but for some reason it's showing **"No results found"**

Is there some special trick I need to do to get the CLI to pick up on this change?

Comment: can you please confirm if expanded source tracking is enabled? https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_source_tracking_beta.htm

Comment: It is currently disabled... should it be enabled?

Comment: Yes. Please try enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

By my observation, the Standard Tab Settings of the Profile are not pulled.

However I found this discussion that explains a way to manually add `tabVisibilities` elements to the `.profile-meta.xml` file, using their "standard" name:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hR9kAAE

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>standard-Account</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

> to get the tab name use chrome and go to Profile Edit page.  let's say you need to get Forecasts tab name.  go to the  Forecasts drop down and right click "Inspect".  it will show  Id="tab___Forecasting3"
>
> copy the id, remove "tab___" ,  and add "standard-" before it.
>   so it become  standard-Forecasting3
>
> so for the Data.com  it will be "standard-JigsawSearch"

The expanded source tracking mentioned in the question comments is not required nor available as of Winter '19.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_sfdx_scratch_orgs_source_tracking.htm

> We discontinued the Expanded Source Tracking beta. The Dev Hub Setup page no longer includes the option to turn on Expanded Source Tracking. Launch the Metadata Coverage report to determine supported metadata for scratch org source tracking purposes. The Metadata Coverage report is the ultimate source of truth for metadata coverage across several channels. These channels include Metadata API, scratch org source tracking, unlocked packages, second-generation managed packages, and classic managed packages.
>
> To access the Metadata Coverage report, go to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage.

If you try to enable the feature in your scratch org definition file, you'll get the following error:

```
ERROR:  ExpandedSourceTracking is not a valid Features value.
```