# How to pull custom object/tab settings from a scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I created a scratch org, made some custom objects and adjusted custom tab settings. I pulled it and pushed it to a newly created scratch org. However, my custom tab settings is not applied and I have to manually go to Setup -> Users -> Profile and adjust the custom tab settings manually.

I have seen a solution from [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/242038/69889), but I don't have `.profile-meta.xml`. Adding `'standard-'` on my `standard__LightningSales.app-meta.xml`, and I got a push error:

> In field: tab - no CustomTab named standard-CustomObjectName__c found

This is the content of **CustomObjectField__c.field-meta.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>CustomObjectField__c</fullName>
    <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>CustomObjectName</label>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Checkbox</type>
</CustomField>
```

How do I get custom object/tab settings so I don't have to set it manually every time I created new scratch org? My goal is to create a batch script to create a scratch org with all the custom objects and the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with scratch orgs, best practice would be to create a Permission Set that grants access to the custom tab / custom object, and auto-assign it after the scratch org has been created with:

```
sfdx force:user:permset:assign -n MyPermissionSet
```

As far as pulling Profile permissions into your local machine, try:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Profile:Admin,Profile:My_Custom_Profile,CustomObject:My_Custom_Object__c -u MyConnectedOrg
```

Comment: Permission set is what I am looking for. Thank you!